# Check if object occurs more than 2 times in list

Tags: python

In python, how do I check if an objects occurs more than 2 times. So basically

```
test = [object1,object2,object1,object1]
#some stuff
test = [object1]
```

or

```
test =[object1,object2,object1,object2,object1,object2]
#some stuff
test =[object1,object2]
```

Comment: You may use `Counter()` to get the frequency distribution of each object and then threshold it on frequencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a']
list(set([x for x in a if a.count(x) > 2]))
```

This returns

```
['a']
```

If you need unique values, wrap it in a set.

Comment: he just wants the items once on the resulting list

Comment: Just note, you are getting quadratic time complexity here.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for pointing that out, I didn't realise that.

Comment: @selten98 I dont think this would be a problem since list size will be maximum 8